# SQL using group_concat with count of each concatenated item rather total count in a row

Tags: mysql, database, count, mariadb, group-concat

[MYSQl - Count of elements inside Group_Concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518457/mysql-count-of-elements-inside-group-concat/55224324#55224324)

I rewrote it as **[this fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mTHmv2idQwkdPZSqmRPi2Z/0)**, but its giving error.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as concerns, to solve the error and get the correct result, you just need to return the `CUSTOMERID` from the aggregated subquery (the column is already part of the `GROUP BY` clause).

Updated query:

```
 SELECT SELLER, 
       COUNT(*) as COUNT_OF_CUSTIDS,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CUSTOMERID, ' (', cnt, ')' SEPARATOR '|') AS CUSTIDS
FROM (
    SELECT SELLER, CUSTOMERID, COUNT(*) as cnt
    FROM docs
    GROUP BY SELLER, CUSTOMERID
) t
GROUP BY SELLER
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Returns:

```
| SELLER | COUNT_OF_CUSTIDS | CUSTIDS              |
| ------ | ---------------- | -------------------- |
| S1     | 3                | C2 (2)|C1 (2)|C3 (3) |
| S2     | 3                | C3 (1)|C2 (1)|C1 (2) |
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mTHmv2idQwkdPZSqmRPi2Z/1)**

Comment: can you please further see into it

Comment: @programmergeeky: this is a different problem than the one I originaly replied to (eg, now you have two tables involved, vs only one in the original question). You would need to ask a new question, that's just how it works here on StackOverflow. Also, I do not understand why you unaccepted my answer, since I think I properly answered you *original* question...

Comment: yes i am new so kind a hard to repost a new qs but i just did